# Building goldfish2.6.29 kernel: no rule to make target "goldfish_armv7_defconfig" stop

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-emulator, arm

build android goldfish kernel 2.6.29 on ubuntu 14.04.
my .sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=~/Android_4.0.1/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin:$PATH
export ARCH=arm
export SUBARCH=arm
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-
make goldfish_armv7_defconfig
make
```

./my.sh export:

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.0.1
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=ITL41D
============================================
make: *** no rule to make target "goldfish_armv7_defconfig". stop.
```

and I have tried ：

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- goldfish_armv7_defconfig
```

The result is still the same：

```
no rule to make target "goldfish_armv7_defconfig". stop.
```

What I am doing wrong?

How to fix it? thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: What instructions are you following that lead you to believe "make goldfish_armv7_defconfig" would work? And why are you trying to build a 6 years old kernel for Android?

Comment: @user1627257 Try 'make kernel'.  There are several other make options, but 'make *_defconfig' is not one of them, AFAIK.